BPMN 2.0: Can sub-processes / event sub-processes have a message end event?
boiling it down to the painpoint:
I wonder, if sub-processes can end with a message end event.
And in addition, does this hold for event sub-processes as well?
(I know that event sub-processes are not allowed to have boundary events.)
The standard does not really talk about this as it seems to be allowed, but that would mean that a subprocess sort of crosses its boundary with a message flow. And looking for examples I literally did not find any on google.
(My process needs to be able to react to input that can "happen" at any time. And after dealing with it, I want to send a message to another pool. Image sth like an event sub-process that listens to a process abortion from another pool (message start event), will process it and then send a message to the other participant "I cancelled it." ... )

-1 ... well thanks. Happy to get sth constructive :)

Well, you haven't been fully accepted in this community unless you get down-voted  so, welcome to Software Engineering. If it helps, I up-voted your down-vote comment. In any event, can you [edit] your question to clarify the use case? I think the semantics of what you are trying to accomplish are important here. My first thought was to make the "message end" event meaningful from a business perspective so it is no longer an "end" but an event to signal a continuation of a business process.

And yes, my "up-vote your down-vote" comment doesn't actually help anything, except that I feel your pain.

I think it could be helpful if you add a BPMN model that demonstrates what you want to communicate. I think we have some people here who are very familiar (I only have a passing familiarity with the notation) who could answer this. But if you can show a clear example of what it would look like, it could make it easier to read and people can say if the notation is correct or provide an correct notation.

Thank you guys. I will update tomorrow as I need to refine my diagrams in order to restrain my wish to squeeze too many single issues into it :)
